# Switch statement many parameters and the same treatment

Tags: c, arduino, switch-statement

I use switch Case to select function the Variable is entred by serial (Ardiuino) Exemple if i write UP or Up even up the same treatment and the same action is called 
I did it but i got a longer text it's possible to reduce it 
 The code is above

```
switch (instruction[0])
    {
     case 'P' :

                  switch (instruction[1])
            {
             case 'A' :
                        PA(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'R' :
                      PR(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'U' :
                      PU(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'D' :
                      PD(x,y);
             break ;  

            case 'a' :
            PA(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'r' :
                      PR(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'u' :
                      PU(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'd' :
                      PD(x,y);
             break ;   
            }

        break;
        case 'p' :

                  switch (instruction[1])
            {
             case 'A' :
                        PA(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'R' :
                      PR(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'U' :
                      PU(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'D' :
                      PD(x,y);
             break ;  

            case 'a' :
            PA(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'r' :
                      PR(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'u' :
                      PU(x,y);
             break ; 
             case 'd' :
                      PD(x,y);
             break ;   
            }              
        break;





     case 'T' :
        Serial.println("error");
        break;
     case 'A' :

            switch(instruction[1])
            {
              case 'A' :
                  AA(x,y,z);
              break;  
              case 'a' :
                AA(x,y,z);
              break;  

            }
        break;

      case 'a':     
            switch(instruction[1])
            {
              case 'A' :
                  AA(x,y,z);
              break;  
              case 'a' :
                AA(x,y,z);
              break;  

            }
        break;
```

}

Comment: You can start by realizing the a simple call to `toupper` can reduce the number of cases in your switch by half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be by using the switch **fall through**. Though in your case, you would have to use it in a nested manner.

Something like this.

```
switch (instruction[0])
{
    case 'P' :
    case 'p' :

        switch (instruction[1])
        {
            case 'A' :
            case 'a' :
                PA(x,y);
            break ; 

            case 'R' :
            case 'r' :
                  PR(x,y);
             break ; 

            case 'U' :
            case 'u' :
                  PU(x,y);
            break ; 

            case 'D' :
            case 'd' :
                  PD(x,y);
            break ;  
        }
    break;
    case 'T' :
    case 't' :
        Serial.println("error");
        break;

    case 'A' :
    case 'a' :
        switch(instruction[1])
        {
            case 'A' :
            case 'a' :
                  AA(x,y,z);
            break;  
        }
    break;
}
```

Note that the default case is not taken care of in the various switch statements. You need to decide what action to take if the user inputs a value of "px". Currently this code takes no action.

Answer (score 0):

Change code like:

```
          case 'A' :
              AA(x,y,z);
          break;  
          case 'a' :
            AA(x,y,z);
          break;
```

to:

```
          case 'A' :
          case 'a' :
              AA(x,y,z);
          break;
```

You still have an absurd amount of code duplication. Why aren't you using something like a lookup table? Or even an `if`/`else if` tree that would eliminate the need for all the `break` statements? Or `toupper`?

Comment: The objective here is to select the action it may wrote in uppercase or tiny (pa,Pa,aP,PA)

Comment: @YoucefAli Yes, and I showed how to do that. Just duplicate the `case` labels without duplicating their code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strcasecmp()` which compares two strings but doesn't care about the case of the characters.

```
if(strcasecmp(instruction, "pa") == 0)
  {
  PA(x,y);
  }
else if(strcasecmp(intruction, "pr") == 0)
  {
  PR(x,y);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how flexible you are with those functions, you could refactor them so that they take the second letter as a parameter.

So, instead of having

```
PA(x,y);
PR(x,y);
PU(x,y);
PD(x,y);
...
```

use

```
P( c, x, y );
```

and hand over `A`, `R`, `U`, `D`, etc (i.e, `instruction[1]`) for the parameter `c`.